# Find out if UDP Broadcast (IPv4) or multicast (IPv6) are enabled in the current network?

Tags: java, ipv6, broadcast, multicast

So I'd like an automated network discovery for  the application I'm currently building, but turns out we're not in a perfect world and neither does every network have IPv6 enabled for multicasting, nor is IPv4 UDP broadcast enabled in every network.

Any idea how I can programmatically find out, if either of those are enabled in the current network? Since UDP doesn't open a connection, I can just throw datagrams and hope someone finds it, then if noone else answers after a set time (or like, offer the user a button for manual discovery from the beginning) use user provided information (or a name service / registry I'd have to host somewhere).

Looks like sending a multicast is received on my own machine when I send it from one port to the other, but I can't be sure it actually goes out of the device and back in or it just loops back because it's being clever.

I'd prefer multicast of course - broadcast would be the fallback here.

**Update**

Tried things in the eduroam network:

Made new `MulticastSocket` and joined the multicast using `joinGroup`.
Made new `DatagramSocker` and sent a message to that multicast group
-> Works locally
-> Doesn't work across machines

Same with broadcast (interfaceAddress.getBroadcast()). Works locally (Sending from one port to another), but not across machines.

So how do I programmatically decide if these work?

Comment: IPv6 multicast is used on _every_ IPv6 network, and IPv4 broadcast is a host requirement (all support either the limited broadcast of `255.255.255.255` or the network broadcast), although broadcast is basically deprecated (many companies reject applications that use broadcast; multicast is the modern way of doing things).

Comment: Ah so I can just iterate through all network NetworkInterface.getNetwotkInterfaces and all their IP addresses and if I find one IPv6 address I can just use multicast?

Comment: Even better: every interface should always have an IPv6 link-local address (starting with fe80:) and because you only need to send a multicast packet to the local link that is all you need.

Comment: But I want to send the multicast to a specific multicast-group so different instances can use different domains to stay in multiple, separate groups, say "FF05::100", do I just send that with the first link-local address I can find as sender and others joining that group will definitely receive it? I feel like I need a diagram lol.

Comment: Tried it, didn't work. Results in post.

Comment: "Tried things in the eduroam network:" Test on a network you own, public wifi networks typically have peer to peer communications blocked

Comment: Well that's exactly the idea here though, I'd like the program to find out whether or not P2P connection are blocked. On my own network, I don't have to find out because I already know.